# Внешний отчет о скидках

Tags: 1с

С Новым Годом!Помогите решить задание начинающему программисту.Мне надо сделать отчет о скидках,т е чтобы в отчете была сумма скидок от продаж.Я так понимаю мне надо будет пробежаться по обычному отчету о продажах,сверить количество проданного товара и цену в справочнике,если они отличаются то посчитать на сколько и т д.
У меня возникили сложности с проверкой суммы из обычного отчета.

Comment: укажите версию платформы, а также конфигурацию и ее редакцию.

Comment: я так понимаю версия 1.82 управление торговлей,внешний отчет.больше ничего не знаю

Comment: > больше ничего не знаю  

И что вы хотите сделать?  

В общем берите книжку по 1С программированию и начинайте читать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Внешний отчет

Это отчет, которого нету в конфигурации, а подключается к клиенту из вне.

> надо будет пробежаться по обычному отчету

вам нужно пробегаться не по отчету, а по регистрам

> отчет о скидках

мне это словосочетание не говорит ни о чем. больше информации об отчете в студию

---

**UPD**

Без знания конфигурации остается только гадать на кофейной гуще.

У вас есть товар. Вы его продаете. При продаже оформляется какой-нибудь документ, допустим счет на оплату покупателю. При проведении этого документа движения отражаются в регистрах (это может быть какой-нибудь регистр накопления "Продажи").

Вот вам надо посмотреть, в каком регистре отражается движение документа. Для этого открываете свойства документа, и там будет вкладка "Движения". Подробнее движения можно посмотреть в модуле объекта в процедуре "Обработка проведения".

Comment: Ну задание в том состоит,что есть скидки которые ставятся вручную.Вот нужно посчитать сумму всех скидок. Объясните пожста как это реализовать тогда и какие регистры использовать. Регистры накопления?